# Micronaut @JsonDeserialize not working as expected

Tags: json-deserialization, micronaut, jackson-databind

**OS:** Windows 11
**JDK:** corretto-17.0.6
**IDE:** IntelliJ IDEA 2022.3.1
**Micronaut Application Version:** 3.7.3

I have a Micronaut application to do some basic IO operations. I have a DTO class that has a duration field, but I want this field to work in milliseconds rather than seconds. Here's my POST request:

```java
    @Post
    public EventBean create(@Body EventBean eventBean) {
        return eventBean;
    }
```

and JSON body sent:

```json
{
    "from": "2023-03-05T12:26:43.538Z",
    "duration": 600000
}
```

expected the same but recieved

```json
{
    "from": "2023-03-05T12:26:43.538Z",
    "duration": 600000000
}
```

and `EventBean` class:

```java
@Introspected
public class EventBean {
    @JsonFormat(shape = JsonFormat.Shape.STRING, pattern = "yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss.SSS'Z'", timezone = "UTC")
    private final Instant from;

    @JsonSerialize(converter = DurationSerializer.class)
    @JsonDeserialize(converter = DurationDeserializer.class)
    private final Duration duration;

    public EventBean(Instant from, Duration duration) {
        this.from = from;
        this.duration = duration;
    }

    public Instant getFrom() {
        return from;
    }

    public Duration getDuration() {
        return duration;
    }

    public static class DurationSerializer extends StdConverter<Duration, Long> {
        @Override public Long convert(Duration value) {
            return value.toMillis();
        }
    }

    public static class DurationDeserializer extends StdConverter<Long, Duration> {
        @Override public Duration convert(Long value) {
            return Duration.ofMillis(value);
        }
    }
}
```

But `DurationDeserializer` class is not being used while deserializing my JSON from body. ( `DurationSerializer` is working just fine )

I also tried using `JsonDeserializer<T>` class and `using` field in `JsonDeserialize` annotation but to no avail.

**EDIT**
I found a workaround, I override the default `DurationDeserializer` by jackson using micronaut `@Replaces` as follows:

```java
@Replaces(value = com.fasterxml.jackson.datatype.jsr310.deser.DurationDeserializer.class)
public class DurationDeserializer extends JsonDeserializer<Duration> {
    @Override public Duration deserialize(JsonParser p, DeserializationContext ctxt)
        throws IOException {
        return Duration.ofMillis(p.getLongValue());
    }
}
```

Comment: I assume the duration in your JSON is a ISO string representation, or can you add the raw json thats being posted onto your controller method?

Comment: @saw303 duration would be milliseconds in my body, raw json added to question

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I recommend to configure date/time serialisation globally in your `application.yml`

```yaml
jackson:
  dateFormat: yyyyMMdd
  timeZone: UTC
  serialization:
    writeDatesAsTimestamps: false
```

This will do the `Instant` deser for you without using any additional Jackson annotation on your POJO.

In order to make the duration deser work you need to make sure that your serializer/deserializer are Micronaut beans and I recommend to have them in separate Java source files.

```java
@Singleton
public class DurationSerializer extends StdConverter<Duration, Long> {
        @Override public Long convert(Duration value) {
            return value.toMillis();
        }
    }

@Singleton
public class DurationDeserializer extends StdConverter<Long, Duration> {
        @Override public Duration convert(Long value) {
            return Duration.ofMillis(value);
        }
}
```